# How can I reliably transfer thousands of files from Windows 7 to OSX Lion

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, osx-lion

Lion seems to have removed FTP as an option for "Share Files" in the Sharing pane, this means I can't connect to it using a robust client like FileZilla.  I have several thousand files that need to be moved.  In the past I've done this by whipping up filezilla, connecting to the Mac, and transferring.  This allowed me to retry individual files that fail, which is inevitable with such a large batch.

Do I have to install an FTP server now? It seems like there has to be a more direct way.  Is the FTP option just hidden away?  Is there some new, better way of doing it?

Comment: Your question title says "copy from win to OSX", but the question seems to say the opposite. Am I confused?

Comment: I don't think I contradict myself -- where do you mean?

Comment: if you are putting an ftp server on your OSX machine, you would be copying from OSX to windows. Also, you talk about setting up a share in the context of the OSX user interface.

Comment: Ahh -- FTP is a two way street.  You can upload to a server or download from a server.  By enabling FTP on OSX you made it act as a server, and you could put files on and copy files off.  I don't care if I push to OSX from win 7 or if I pull from win7 on OSX, either way the files get moved from the PC to OSX.  (also the ideal solution would support both directions as well)

Comment: I understand, thanks. Knowing OSX' roots in unix-like OS, I'd expect the ftp server to be built-in and configurable from terminal at the very least. (edit: it is AFAICT http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20088844-263/managing-ftp-services-in-os-x-lion/ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would compress all of your files into one large archive file with something like 7zip or Rar and then just transfer one large file.  Make sure the compression program you choose is cross platform.

Comment: It's even possible to `tar cz` on on machine, pipe the output across an ssh connection, and `tar xz` on the other machine. No wasted disk space, and very efficient in my experience; given that transfers of tons of small files are rather slow.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use 7zip and compress all of the files into one archive
2. Download an SFTP program for Windows(such as [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) )
3. Turn on "Remote Login" on OSX
4. Connect to your Mac box from Windows using the SFTP program.
5. Transfer archive
6. Profit!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a USB external drive (so long as it's not NTFS formatted), that'd be another approach.

Comment: Indeed!  I don't have one handy but that's a nice KISS solution.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I needed to do this, I installed Cygwin on windows and turned on "Remote Login" (ssh) on OS X. Then I could scp the files from the PC to the Mac (or pull from the Mac to the PC).

Comment: What's a good source for cygwin?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I have Cygwin already installed so I may try that.  However, this seems a bit like hitting a hammer with a bulldozer... I'd be more comfortable just installing an FTP server on either the mac or the PC over something as major/invasive/whatever you want to call it as Cygwin.  Then again maybe I have a skewed perception of Cygwin.

Comment: Use a GUI SCP client that won't require any Cygwin installation/usage. I personally use the portableapps version of WinSCP, but I'm sure there are other free SCP clients available as well.

Comment: @slifty This was my work computer that came with Cygwin - I second Matrix Mole's suggestion of a GUI client.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a share on the windows machine. Connect to that (SMB) with the mac. Now use rsync to do the actual transfer, using the mount point on the mac:

```
rsync -avP /Volumes/ShareName/* ~/Destination/
```

This way, if your SMB connection flakes out you can just rerun the rsync command to pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make a share in Windows and pull those files from Lion side by samba connection?

Edit: OK, I got the info samba connection to Windows is not considered "reliable".

Now that there is already cygwin installed on Windows, the best way is to do this in cygwin:

```
tar cf - ./* | ssh someone@lion tar -C /destination/ -f - -x
```

This will save a lot of overhead compared to individual files being transferred over scp.

Comment: OS X has always been rather flaky with its SMB support in my experience. There's a reason there are tons of troubleshooting questions related to it on this site.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the suggestion -- I've found the native share to fail with large jobs (and when that happens I don't know what files made it).  I'm trying to avoid a cygwin-based solution since I personally think cygwin is overkill for this specific problem, but good to know!